# pygame.time.delay() doesn't display the text message for required time

Tags: python, time, pygame

I am trying to create a 5 second long display message for every time the user presses "Return". But the program just pauses for 5 seconds and displays the message for 1 millisecond. This is just a rough representation of the type of code i tried to use.

```
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        text = font.render("You pressed Return", True,(0,0,0))
        win.blit(text, (350,350))
    pygame.display.update()
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:    
        pygame.time.delay(5000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) after `pygame.display.update()`. On some systems the update of the display is finished during the internal event handling. e.g:

```py
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        text = font.render("You pressed Return", True,(0,0,0))
        win.blit(text, (350,350))
    pygame.display.update()
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        pygame.event.pump() # <----
        pygame.time.delay(5000)
```

---

Anyway I won't do it like that, because the system is not responding, when the application is delayed.
Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) to draw the text for a time span.

Get the current time in milliseconds:

```py
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

When <kbd>RETURN</kbd> is pressed, then compute the time when the text has to disapear:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
    pause_time = current_time + 5000
```

Draw the text as long `text_time` is grater than `current_time`:

e.g.:

```py
running = True
text_time = 0
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        text_time = current_time + 5000

    win.fill((255,255,255))
    if text_time > current_time:
        text = font.render("You pressed Return", True,(0,0,0))
        win.blit(text, (350,350))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using time and waiting for 5 seconds. Also i wouldn't recommend using `pygame.time.delay(100)` every frame. You can use clock

```
import time

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Show_Text = False
Start_show_text = 0

while running:
    clock.tick(60) #this limits the fps to 60
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    win.fill((255,255,255))

    if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        Show_Text = True
        Start_show_text = time.time()

    if Show_Text:
        if time.time() - Start_show_text < 5: #if its been less than 5 seconds
            text = font.render("You pressed Return", True,(0,0,0))
            win.blit(text, (350,350))
        else:
            Show_Text = False

    pygame.display.update()
```